# Index out of Range in Self - BERT Model Tuning Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, nlp, indexoutofboundsexception, bert-language-model

I am working on training the BERT Model for Pytorch. I'm quite new to Pytorch as well. My code as replicated from: https://towardsdatascience.com/text-classification-with-bert-in-pytorch-887965e5820f keeps returning an error: "Index out of Range in Self". The training partially executed but then abruptly stops with this exception. My code below:

```
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
```

```
labels = {'prepared' : 0,
          'anticipating' : 1,
          'hopeful' : 2,
          'proud' : 3,
          'excited' : 4,
          'joyful' : 5,
          'content' : 6, 
          'caring' : 7, 
          'grateful' : 8, 
          'trusting' : 9, 
          'confident' : 10, 
          'faithful' : 11, 
          'impressed' : 12, 
          'surprised' : 13, 
          'terrified' : 14, 
          'afraid' : 15, 
          'apprehensive' : 16, 
          'anxious' : 17, 
          'embarrassed' : 18, 
          'ashamed' : 19, 
          'devastated' : 20, 
          'sad' : 21, 
          'disappointed' : 22, 
          'lonely' : 23, 
          'sentimental' : 24, 
          'nostalgic' : 25, 
          'guilty' : 26, 
          'disgusted' : 27, 
          'furious' : 28, 
          'angry' : 29, 
          'annoyed' : 30, 
          'jealous' : 31, 
          'agreeing' : 32, 
          'acknowledging' : 33, 
          'encouraging' : 34, 
          'consoling' : 35, 
          'sympathizing' : 36, 
          'suggesting' : 37, 
          'questioning' : 38, 
          'wishing' : 39, 
          'neutral' : 40}

class Dataset(torch.utils.data.Dataset):

    def __init__(self, df):

        self.labels = [labels[label] for label in df['eb+_emot']]
        self.texts = [tokenizer(text, 
                               padding='max_length', max_length = 510, truncation=True,
                                return_tensors="pt") for text in df['uttr']]

    def classes(self):
        return self.labels

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.labels)

    def get_batch_labels(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of labels
        return np.array(self.labels[idx])

    def get_batch_texts(self, idx):
        # Fetch a batch of inputs
        return self.texts[idx]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):

        batch_texts = self.get_batch_texts(idx)
        batch_y = self.get_batch_labels(idx)
    
        return batch_texts, batch_y
```

```
np.random.seed(112)
df_train, df_val, df_test = np.split(df.sample(frac = 1, random_state= 42), 
                                     [int(.8*len(df)), int(.9*len(df))])

print(len(df_train), len(df_val), len(df_test))
```

```
from torch import nn
from transformers import BertModel
```

```
class BertClassifier(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, dropout=0.5):

        super(BertClassifier, self).__init__()

        self.bert = BertModel.from_pretrained('bert-base-cased')
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(768, 41)
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()

    def forward(self, input_id, mask):

        _, pooled_output = self.bert(input_ids= input_id, attention_mask=mask,return_dict=False)
        dropout_output = self.dropout(pooled_output)
        linear_output = self.linear(dropout_output)
        final_layer = self.relu(linear_output)

        return final_layer
```

```
from torch.optim import Adam
from tqdm import tqdm
```

```
def train(model, train_data, val_data, learning_rate, epochs):

    train, val = Dataset(train_data), Dataset(val_data)

    train_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train, batch_size=2)
    val_dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val, batch_size=2)

    use_cuda = torch.cuda.is_available()
    device = torch.device("cuda" if use_cuda else "cpu")

    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    optimizer = Adam(model.parameters(), lr= learning_rate)

    if use_cuda:

            model = model.cuda()
            criterion = criterion.cuda()

    for epoch_num in range(epochs):

            total_acc_train = 0
            total_loss_train = 0

            for train_input, train_label in tqdm(train_dataloader):

                train_label = train_label.to(device)
                mask = train_input['attention_mask'].to(device)
                input_id = train_input['input_ids'].squeeze(1).to(device)

                output = model(input_id, mask)
                
                batch_loss = criterion(output, train_label.long())
                total_loss_train += batch_loss.item()
                
                acc = (output.argmax(dim=1) == train_label).sum().item()
                total_acc_train += acc

                model.zero_grad()
                batch_loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
            
            total_acc_val = 0
            total_loss_val = 0

            with torch.no_grad():

                for val_input, val_label in val_dataloader:

                    val_label = val_label.to(device)
                    mask = val_input['attention_mask'].to(device)
                    input_id = val_input['input_ids'].squeeze(1).to(device)

                    output = model(input_id, mask)

                    batch_loss = criterion(output, val_label.long())
                    total_loss_val += batch_loss.item()
                    
                    acc = (output.argmax(dim=1) == val_label).sum().item()
                    total_acc_val += acc
            
            print(
                f'Epochs: {epoch_num + 1} | Train Loss: {total_loss_train / len(train_data): .3f} \
                | Train Accuracy: {total_acc_train / len(train_data): .3f} \
                | Val Loss: {total_loss_val / len(val_data): .3f} \
                | Val Accuracy: {total_acc_val / len(val_data): .3f}')
                  
EPOCHS = 5
model = BertClassifier()
LR = 1e-6
              
train(model, df_train, df_val, LR, EPOCHS)
```

I've found some other solutions that people posed around 'embedding', but I'm quite new to this syntax so I'm not sure where to actually edit my code (hence the plethora that I've posted).